# Using virtual environments to manage develop/deploy packages in Jupyterhub

Tags: python, ipython, virtualenv, jupyter

I have a package that I am developing for a local server. I would like to have the current stable release importable in a Jupyter notebook using `import my_package` and the current development state importable (for end-to-end testing and stuff) with `import my_package_dev`, or something like that.

The package is version controlled with git. The `master` branch holds the stable release, and new development work is done in the `develop` branch.

I currently pulled these two branches into two different folders:

```
my_package/  # tracks master branch of repository
    setup.py
    requirements.txt
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        # other stuff

my_package_dev/  # tracks develop branch of repository
    setup.py
    requirements.txt
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        # other stuff for dev branch
```

My `setup.py` file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
      name='my_package',  # or 'my_package_dev' for the dev version
      # metadata stuff...
     )
```

I can `pip install my_package` just fine, but I have been unable to get anything to link to the name `my_package_dev` in Python.

### Things I have tried

- `pip install my_package_dev`

  Doesn't seem to overwrite the existing `my_package`, but doesn't seem to make `my_package_dev` available either, even though pip says it finishes OK.
- `pip install -e my_package_dev`

  makes an egg and puts the development package path in `easy-install.pth`, but I cannot `import my_package_dev`, and `my_package` is still the old content.
- Adding a file `my_package_dev.pth` to site-packages directory and filling it with `/path/to/my_package_dev`

  causes no visible change. Still does not allow me to `import my_package_dev`.

### Thoughts on a solution

It looks like the best approach is going to be to use virtual environments, as discussed in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by Gonzalo got me on the right track: use virtual environments to manage two different builds. I created the virtual environment for the master (stable) branch with:

```sh
$ cd my_package
$ virtualenv venv  # make the virtual environment
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install -r requirements.txt  # install everything listed as a requirement
(venv) $ pip install -e .  # install my_package dynamicially so that any changes are visible right away
(venv) $ sudo venv/bin/python -m ipykernel install --name 'master' --display-name 'Python 3 (default)'
```

And for the develop branch, I followed the same procedure in my `my_package_dev` folder, giving it a different `--name` and `--display-name` value.

Note that I needed to use `sudo` for the final `ipykernel install` command because I kept getting permission denied errors on my system. I would recommend trying without `sudo` first, but for this system it needed to be installed system-wide.

Finally, to switch between which version of the tools I am using, I just have to select `Kernel -> Change kernel` and choose `Python 3 (default)` or `Python 3 (develop)`. The import stays the same (`import my_package`), so nothing in the *notebook* has to change.

This isn't quite my ideal scenario since it means that I will then have to re-run the whole notebook any time I change kernels, but it works!

Answer (score 2):

With **pip install** you install packages by its name in setup.py's name attribute. If you have installed both and execute **pip freeze**, you will see both packages listed. Which code is available depends on how they are included in Python path.

The issue is those two packages contains just a python module named **my_package**, that it why you can not import **my_package_dev** (it does not exist).

I would suggest you to have an working copy for each version (without modifying package name) and use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to keep environments isolated (one virtualenv for stable version and the other for dev).
You could also use pip's editable install to keep the environment updated with the working copies.

Note: Renaming *my_package_dev's my_package* module directory to *my_package_dev*, will also work. But it will be harder to merge changes from one version to the other.

Comment: I like the virtual environment idea, but I don't know that maintaining separate environments is feasible for our application, at least not yet. I will work on that, but in the mean time where is the package getting its import name from if not from the `name` argument, and is there a way to force it to import with some specified name?

Comment: The package and module name are 2 different things. The first one is defined in setup.py's name and it is what you install with pip. The module name (Python standard module) is determined by the directory name.

Comment: Short answer: Just rename the directory.

Comment: OK, thanks! I think the virtual environment idea is the way to go, otherwise I'm worried about diverging branches with different folder names...